# Flex justify content end bootstrap nav items

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

**Codepen** -> https://codepen.io/SubSul/pen/LgWzVw.

I have modified the bootstrap 4 navbar component to include a fixed button dropdown  for login on the top right corner. I'm now trying to align the nav-items to the stick against the login button, but `justify-content: flex-end` does not seems be pushing this to the right.

I tried adding margin-left to the nav-items, to no avail.

On the desktop I'm trying to achieve this -

[image]

And on the mobile, I'm trying to get the logo center aligned and login button stick to the right. I'm able to use `margin-right` to move the logo to the center, but the transition on click of hamburger shifts the logo a little to the left, how do I leave it fixed to the center -

[image]

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<div class="main">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar Logo</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarText">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="login-widget">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Log In
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
      <form class="px-4 py-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleDropdownFormEmail1">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleDropdownFormEmail1" placeholder="email@example.com">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleDropdownFormPassword1">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleDropdownFormPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="dropdownCheck">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="dropdownCheck">
            Remember me
          </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
      </form>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New around here? Sign up</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Styles

```
.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.navbar-collapse {
  /* margin-left: 100%; */
}
.login-widget {
  /* margin-left: 320px; */
}
```

Comment: To the minus voters, care to drop a comment to justify your vote ?

Comment: Add your code to your question.

Comment: There's a codepen linked towards the end of the question. minus votes even before reading the question completely, ridiculous!

Comment: Yes I can see that you have a codepen link. The problem is that if you change the code on the linked codepen, or delete the codepen entirely, this StackOverflow question (and any answers, discussions regarding it) becomes useless.

Comment: gotcha, thanks for the rationale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with a solution for this, it's not the cleanest I've made but maybe it will work for you, I didn't use flexbox to do it so you can delete the .main css, first off all you need to move the .login-widget div inside the nav tag, doing that it's gonna look as you want for desktop.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar Logo</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarText">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="login-widget">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Log In
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <form class="px-4 py-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleDropdownFormEmail1">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleDropdownFormEmail1" placeholder="email@example.com">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleDropdownFormPassword1">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleDropdownFormPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="dropdownCheck">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="dropdownCheck">
                    Remember me
                </label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
            </form>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New around here? Sign up</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
            </div>
        </div>

</nav>
```

But we will have a problem on mobile devices, when you click on the hamburger menu the .login-widget div it's going to align with the other nav items of the menu,
breaking your layout, so what I do to fix this, it's giving to .login-widget a position absolute

```
.login-widget{
    position: absolute;
    right: 16px;
    top: 4px;
}
```

that will do the trick for .login-widget, but now we have another problem .navbar-brand isn't centered, so what I do to fix it's using position absolute again

```
.navbar-brand{
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: calc(109px + 16px);
    left: calc(56px + 16px);
    text-align: center;
}
```

and for the last, you have to wrap this classes in a media query to reset the values for desktop.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px){
    .login-widget{
        position: static;
        right: auto;
        top: auto;
    }

    .navbar-brand{
        position: static;
        top: auto;
        right: auto;
        left: auto;
        text-align: left;
    }
}
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/federicomartin/pen/OaXBdp) you have a codepen if you wanna test it, let me know if that's the solution you are looking for!

Comment: Cant thank you enough for your help here. As a sever side dev, I did learn quite a bit of positioning in CSS from your post. Thanks. +1 and accepting the answer.

Comment: can you pls tell me how you arrived at 109px and 56px to align the logo to center? Just trying to learn the concepts here.

Comment: Hello!, I'm glad to help! the logo is centered between the hamburger button and the login button; by default, bootstrap uses a 16px padding for the .navbar class but the logo is in an absolute position, that means it will not respect that, so what I did there, using the css calc function is add that 16px to the right and left plus the width of the two elements, 109px is the width of the login button, and 56px is the width of the hamburguer button.

Comment: Got it, Thanks buddy.